# Info window with place details is not showing (Google Places API)

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I created a city specific film production company locator. I'm using the nearbySearch service with pagination of all places. Until that point everything is working fine.
Now I'm trying to add the getDetails service to display company info in an info window. Unfortanly I didn't figure out how to display an info window for each marker with the data from the getDetails service. I would be very thankful if someone can help me out to solve my problem! I put the code below!

```js
      var map;
      var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
      var labelIndex = 0;


      function initMap() {
        // Create the map.
        var duesseldorf = {lat: 51.2277, lng: 6.7735};
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: duesseldorf,
          zoom: 12
        });


        // Create the places service.
        var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
        var getNextPage = null;
        var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
        moreButton.onclick = function() {
          moreButton.disabled = true;
          if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
        };
        

        // Perform a nearby search.
        service.nearbySearch(
            {location: duesseldorf, radius: 14000, keyword: ['filmproduktion']},
            function(results, status, pagination) {
              if (status !== 'OK') return;

              createMarkers(results);
              moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
              getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
                pagination.nextPage();
              };
            });
        }


        //display place details in info window
        var request = {
            placeId: 'ChIJN1t_tDeuEmsRUsoyG83frY4',
            fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'place_id', 'geometry']
          };
  
          var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
          var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  
          service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
              var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: place.geometry.location
              });
              google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                  'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                  place.formatted_address + '</div>');
                infowindow.open(map, this);
              });
            }
          });
          


      function createMarkers(places) {
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var placesList = document.getElementById('places');


        for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

          var image = {
            url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
            size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
            origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
            anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
            scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
          };

          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
            map: map,
            title: place.name,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });



          var li = document.createElement('li');
          li.textContent = place.name;
          placesList.appendChild(li);


          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
        map.fitBounds(bounds);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
       #map {
        height: 620px;
        width: 75%;
        margin-left: 3%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }

      h1 {
          text-align: center;
          margin-top: 60px;
          margin-bottom: 60px;
          font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
          font-size: 40px;
      }


      #right-panel {
        font-family: 'Roboto','sans-serif';
        line-height: 30px;
        padding: 10px;
      }

      #right-panel select, #right-panel input {
        font-size: 15px;
      }

      #right-panel select {
        width: 100%;
      }

      #right-panel i {
        font-size: 12px;
      }
      #right-panel {
        font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        position: absolute;
        right: 3%;
        height: 600px;
        width: 300px;
        z-index: 5;
        border: 1px solid #999;
        background: #fff;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
      }
      h2 {
        font-size: 22px;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0;
      }
      ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        height: 500px;
        width: 300px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
      }
      li {
        background-color: #f1f1f1;
        padding: 10px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
      }
      li:nth-child(odd) {
        background-color: #fcfcfc;
      }
      #more {
        width: 100%;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
      }

      /* Media Queries */

      @media(max-width: 768px){
          #map{
              display: block;
              width: 90%;
              margin: auto;
              height: 300px;
          }

          #right-panel{
              display: block;
              margin: auto;
              position: relative;
              right: 0;
              margin-top: 15px;
              height: 400px;
          }

          ul{
              height: 300px;
          }

          h1{
              font-size: 30px;
              margin-top: 40px;
              margin-bottom: 40px;
          }
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Place Search Pagination</title>
    <script src="map.js"></script>
  </head>
  <header>
    <h1>Die besten Filmproduktionen in Düsseldorf und Umgebung!</h1>
  </header>
  <body>
      <div id="map"></div>
      <div id="right-panel">
        <h2>Filmproduktionen in Düsseldorf</h2>
        <ul id="places"></ul>
        <button id="more">Mehr Ergebnisse</button>
      </div>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What happens currently?

Comment: @AluanHaddad the nearby search and the pagination is working fine. But the info window is not displaying with the getDeatils data is not showing when the user clicks on a marker.

Comment: My plan is it to build it like this example: https://www.wpmapspro.com/example/paginated-markers-listing-below-google-maps/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get a javascript error with the posted code: `Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined` on this line: `var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();`, because that is outside of `initMap` so executes before the API is loaded.  Make it global (`var infowindow;`), then initialize it inside `initMap`.

```
var infowindow;
function initMap() {
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
```

Then to open the details in the `infowindow`, call the `getDetails` request when the marker is clicked, opening the `infowindow` when the response comes back, keeping track of the reference to the `marker` from the click event (the `var that=this;` line, that gives you function closure on `that` so it is available when the response comes back to the `getDetails` request):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
  //display place details in info window
  var request = {
    placeId: this.place_id,
    fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'place_id', 'geometry']
  };

  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var that = this;
  service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: place.geometry.location
      });
      infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
        'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
        place.formatted_address + '</div>');
      infowindow.open(map, that);
    }
  });
});
```

```js
var map;
var labels = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890';
var labelIndex = 0;
var infowindow;


function initMap() {
  // Create the map.
  var duesseldorf = {
    lat: 51.2277,
    lng: 6.7735
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: duesseldorf,
    zoom: 12
  });
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

  // Create the places service.
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  var getNextPage = null;
  var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
  moreButton.onclick = function() {
    moreButton.disabled = true;
    if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
  };


  // Perform a nearby search.
  service.nearbySearch({
      location: duesseldorf,
      radius: 14000,
      keyword: ['filmproduktion']
    },
    function(results, status, pagination) {
      if (status !== 'OK') return;

      createMarkers(results);
      moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
      getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function() {
        pagination.nextPage();
      };
    });
}





function createMarkers(places) {
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  var placesList = document.getElementById('places');


  for (var i = 0, place; place = places[i]; i++) {

    var image = {
      url: 'https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png',
      size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
      origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
      anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
      scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
    };

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      label: labels[labelIndex++ % labels.length],
      map: map,
      place_id: place.place_id,
      title: place.name,
      position: place.geometry.location
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(e) {
      //display place details in info window
      var request = {
        placeId: this.place_id,
        fields: ['name', 'formatted_address', 'place_id', 'geometry']
      };


      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      var that = this;
      service.getDetails(request, function(place, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: place.geometry.location
          });
          infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
            'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
            place.formatted_address + '</div>');
          infowindow.open(map, that);
        }
      });
    });


    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.textContent = place.name;
    placesList.appendChild(li);


    bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 620px;
  width: 75%;
  margin-left: 3%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  font-size: 40px;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding: 10px;
}

#right-panel select,
#right-panel input {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#right-panel select {
  width: 100%;
}

#right-panel i {
  font-size: 12px;
}

#right-panel {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  right: 3%;
  height: 600px;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 5;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 500px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

li {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  padding: 10px;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
}

#more {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 5px 0 0 0;
}


/* Media Queries */

@media(max-width: 768px) {
  #map {
    display: block;
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 300px;
  }
  #right-panel {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 15px;
    height: 400px;
  }
  ul {
    height: 300px;
  }
  h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
  <title>Place Search Pagination</title>
  <script src="map.js"></script>
</head>
<header>
  <h1>Die besten Filmproduktionen in Düsseldorf und Umgebung!</h1>
</header>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="right-panel">
    <h2>Filmproduktionen in Düsseldorf</h2>
    <ul id="places"></ul>
    <button id="more">Mehr Ergebnisse</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&libraries=places&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help @geocodezip ! Do I also need to use the google.maps.event.addListener to open the info window when the user is clicking on one of the li's?

Comment: You could use `addDomListener` (the `<li>` isn't a google maps javascript API object, it is a DOM object), best to trigger a click on the targeted marker so it uses the existing code to open the infowindow.  If this answered your question, please [accept it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: I accepted it. Your site http://www.geocodezip.com/ helped me a lot to improve my application, thanks!